# Weird Divide by Zero Error in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query :

```
-- There are a select and joins in the query
--Then I have this Where part
WHERE
(
    dbo.Table.Furnished IS NULL
    OR dbo.Table.Furnished = 0
)
AND (
    dbo.Table.Type2 = N'House'
)
AND (
    dbo.Table.Type3 = N'ForSale'
)
AND (
    dbo.Table.FixedArea/ dbo.Table.ToiletNumber< 250
)
AND (
    dbo.Table.FixedArea> 25
)

AND (
    CASE
    WHEN dbo.Table.Segment1 = 1 THEN
        'FirstGroup'
    WHEN dbo.Table.Segment1 = 2 THEN
        'SecondGroup'
    WHEN dbo.Table.Segment1 = 3 THEN
        'ThirdGroup'
    ELSE
        'Undefined'
    END <> 'Undefined'
)
AND (
    dbo.Table.Segment2 <> N'Undefined'
)
OR 
(
    dbo.Table.Furnished IS NULL
    OR dbo.Table.Furnished = 0
)
AND (
    dbo.Table.Type2 = N'Commercial'
)
AND (
    dbo.Table.Type3 = N'ForSale'
)
AND (
    dbo.Table.FixedArea/ dbo.Table.ToiletNumber< 250
)
AND (
    dbo.Table.FixedArea> 25
)

AND (
    CASE
    WHEN dbo.Table.Segment1 = 1 THEN
        'FirstGroup'
    WHEN dbo.Table.Segment1 = 2 THEN
        'SecondGroup'
    WHEN dbo.Table.Segment1 = 3 THEN
        'ThirdGroup'
    ELSE
        'Undefined'
    END <> 'Undefined'
)
AND (
    dbo.Table.Segment2 <> N'Undefined'
)
```

When I add this part below at the bottom of my original query (which doesn't have any division or something like that), I get `Divide by zero error encountered.`

```
OR
    (
        dbo.Table.Geo IS NOT NULL
    )
AND (
    dbo.Table.FixedArea > 0
)
AND (
    dbo.Table.Price > 0
)
AND (
    dbo.Table.RoomNumber LIKE N'%+%'
)
AND (
    dbo.Table.Furnished IS NULL
    OR dbo.Table.Furnished = 0
)
AND(
dbo.Table.Type3 = N'ForRent'
)
```

Why am I getting this divide by zero error? I'm not adding any division. I'm just adding some new filters. Please help me with this error. Thanks.

Comment: The where clause evaluation order may change when you add new conditions.

Comment: You are mixing OR and AND without specifying their scope with proper parenthesis. Even if it work you will end up with unpredictable results.

Comment: One of your added last conditions probably changes the data so `dbo.Table.FixedArea/ dbo.Table.ToiletNumber< 250` now has a divide by 0 error

Comment: You may also have a division outside what you are showing us. Since you only included the WHERE clause, we cannot reliably help.

Comment: @ThomasG I added parantheses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You actually do here `dbo.Table.FixedArea/ dbo.Table.ToiletNumber< 250`...and probably `ToiletNumber` is zero

EDIT: Try re-running your query by changing the above code to

```
dbo.Table.FixedArea / NULLIF(dbo.Table.ToiletNumber, 0) < 250
```

Comment: What I can't understand is it works when I don't add the second code part(which doesn't have any division, as I mentioned in the question). But when I add the second part it does not work.

Comment: @jason in that I case it seems that your conditions in the second part return more rows, which some of them contain 0 as value of ToiletNumber. Try adding NULLIF(ToiletNumber, 0) and rerun your query

Answer (score 1):

You div/0 is here:

```
 (
    dbo.Table.FixedArea/ dbo.Table.ToiletNumber < 250
)
```

This:

```
AND (
    dbo.Table.FixedArea> 25
)
```

Probably removed any div/0

Now this:

```
AND (
    dbo.Table.FixedArea > 0
)
```

Means that rows with a FixedArea between 0 and 25 probably has a 0 for ToiletNumber, and has to be evaluated

To fix:

```
case when ToiletNumber = 0 then 1
     else dbo.Table.FixedArea/ dbo.Table.ToiletNumber
end <250
```